# Why does stderr in subprocess.check_call receive both stderr and stdout streams?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I have a python script (call it `my_python_script.py`) that prints a few messages using

```
print message_string
```

It also outputs percentage progress using

```
sys.stdout.write(progress_string)
```

When it is done, it outputs some statistics and because I later want to gather those in a file via `stderr`, I use

```
sys.stderr.write(stats_string)
```

Now, in another script I call the above script with `subprocess.check_call()` like this

```
file_obj = open('stats.log', 'a')
check_call(['my_python_script.py'], stderr=file_obj)
file_obj.close()
```

To my surprise, `file_obj` contains every output from `my_python_script.py` including `print` output, `sys.stdout.write` output and `sys.stderr.write` output. I expected it would only contain output from `sys.stderr.write`.

Why is this not the case? Does `check_call` redirect `stderr` to `stdout` by default?

If there is an easy fix I would be a happy camper. Thanks.

By the way, I use Python 2.7 on Linux Fedora.

Comment: If you have your script print `sys.stdout.fileno()` and `sys.stderr.fileno()` do they come out the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sincerest apologies to the community!!

This was totally an error on my part.

The key to this error was twofold.

Part one was this definition

```
file_obj = open('stats.log', 'a')
```

Notice the 'a' - it is deliberate but part of the problem. Secondly, I forgot to delete the resulting file after completion (it is supposed to be temporary and is copied to a different location at the end). Because of this, all my test runs accumulated into this file including an initial one where I used stdout.

Oh lord. So the question is: Should I delete the original question or could it be useful for illustrative purposes? It seems so stupid now.

Comment: I would delete the question, since it won't be of any use to future visitors to the site. Thanks for letting us know the outcome.

Comment: I tried, but was not allowed to. Instead, I have flagged it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the stdout option as well:

```
check_call(['my_python_script.py'], stdout=anotherfile_obj, stderr=file_obj)
```

My guess is that `check_call` is treating `stderr` as `stdout` when `stdout` is not specified.

Either that, or your script is printing to `stderr` by default

Comment: `PIPE` might not be the best test, as the [documentation explicitly warns against using it with `check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)

Comment: I know. It can deadlock. However, it was a quick way to test your theory ;-)